# Break a full name into a dictionary of its parts

Tags: python, strings, parsing

It seems like I'm repeating myself here. Is there a standard way to deal with code like this?

```
def getNameParts(name):
    """Return a dictionary of a name's parts.
    name: e.g. 'JOHNSON, John Roberts, Jr. (Jack)'
    Ignores nicknames.
    """
    csSplit = name.split(', ')
    try:
        last = csSplit[0]
    except:
        last = ''
    try:
        first = csSplit[1].split(' ')[0]
    except:
        first = ''
    try:
        middle = ' '.join(csSplit[1].split(' ')[1:])
    except:
        middle = ''
    try:
        suffix = csSplit[2].split(' ')[0]
    except:
        suffix = ''
    partsDict = {'first': first,
                 'last': last,
                 'middle': middle,
                 'suffix': suffix}
    return(partsDict)
```

Comment: I don't see the logic.  It is guaranteed that `csSplit[0]` will *never throw an error* because a split, even on an empty string, will still have at least one item in the result.  What are all these `try` blocks guarding against?

Comment: @zondo the list indexes are out of range for `[1]` and `[2]`. I guess I can remove the try/except for `last`.

Comment: Is your function supposed to work for `'John Roberts, Jr.'`?

Comment: @zondo No, it just needs to work for strings in the format I've written in the docstring.

Comment: Just in case you are ever going to use this in production, be sure to read https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ first.

Answer (score 9):

You have some unnecessary `try` blocks.  Watch this:

```
>>> 'this'.split(', ')
['this']
>>> ''.split(', ')
['']
```

Look, Ma!  No empty lists!  Since a split will always have at least one item in the result, you don't need to `try` to get the first item.  It will always be there for you.  Watch this:

```
>>> [][1:]
[]
>>> ' '.join([])
''
```

Look, Ma!  No errors!  A slice never throws errors, and a `' '.join()` will return `''` when the argument is empty.  That means that you need only one `try` block for `first` and `middle`.

---

An `except` block should specify what it is expecting.  A bare `except` is dangerous. I have found myself caught when I have done that because I can't even interrupt the script with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  If it isn't an `IndexError` that trips the `except`, we want to know about it.  We don't want to hide it under an `except`.

---

Your naming does not comply with PEP 8 (the Python style guide).  It says to use `lowercase_with_underscores` for function and variable names.  Besides that, `csSplit` is a little hard to understand.  Sure, one can recognize `cs` as being short for `comma-separated` if one thinks about it,  but I prefer something a little bit easier to understand.  Keeping the same spirit, why not `comma_split`?  I don't really like that name, but it seems a little easier to understand that `csSplit`.

---

It doesn't make much difference with short strings, but `first` and `middle` both perform the same split operation.  To speed things up, make the split only once by assigning a variable to it.

---

Why the intermediate variable `partsDict`?  We know that the function returns a dictionary of parts by its name and doc string.  Therefore, the variable cannot be for clarity.  It is longer to use than a simple `return`, so it isn't for line length.  Why then?  Just return directly.

---

The code ends up looking like this:

```
def get_name_parts(name):
    """Return a dictionary of a name's parts.
    name: e.g. 'JOHNSON, John Roberts, Jr. (Jack)'
    Ignores nicknames.
    """
    comma_split = name.split(', ')
    last = comma_split[0]

    try:
        first_mid = comma_split[1].split(' ')
    except IndexError:
        first_mid = ['']

    first = first_mid[0]
    middle = ' '.join(first_mid[1:])

    try:
        suffix = comma_split[2].split(' ')[0]
    except IndexError:
        suffix = ''

    return {'first': first,
            'last': last,
            'middle': middle,
            'suffix': suffix}
```

Is it shorter?  Not really.  It is only two or three lines shorter, but it is clearer, less repetitive, and safer.  Happy coding!

Comment: I am especially glad to hear about the error free string indexing. I also recently got stuck in a bare exception, not able to escape with `Ctrl+c`, so I know exactly what you mean - way better to avoid that. I also learned that you can get out of it if needed by sending `SIGQUIT` with `Ctrl+\\`, at least in many terminals.

Answer (score 7):

By [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), function names should be `lower_case_with_underscores`.  In my opinion, the "get" could (and therefore should) be dropped, since the function isn't really retrieving existing data.

The docstring would be clearer and more useful as a [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html).

It's hard to keep track of which string contains what, with all that splitting.  String analysis is usually best done using regular expressions.  The whole function could be a one-liner, using [named capture groups](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups).

```
import re

def name_parts(name):
    """
    Return a dictionary of a name's parts, ignoring nicknames.

    >>> sorted(name_parts('JOHNSON, John Roberts, Jr. (Jack)').items())
    [('first', 'John'), ('last', 'JOHNSON'), ('middle', 'Roberts'), ('suffix', 'Jr.')]
    >>> sorted(name_parts('JOHNSON, John').items())
    [('first', 'John'), ('last', 'JOHNSON'), ('middle', ''), ('suffix', '')]
    >>> sorted(name_parts('JOHNSON').items())
    [('first', ''), ('last', 'JOHNSON'), ('middle', ''), ('suffix', '')]
    """
    # This match always succeeds, since all components are optional
    return re.match(
        '(?P<last>[^,]*),?\s*'
        '(?P<first>[^ ]*)\s*'
        '(?P<middle>[^,]*),?\s*'
        '(?P<suffix>[^ ]*)',
        name
    ).groupdict()
```

Comment: `>>> sorted(name_parts('JOHNSON, John, Jr.').items())
    [('first', 'John'), ('last', 'JOHNSON'), ('middle', ''), ('suffix', 'Jr.')]`

Comment: `'(?P<first>[^ ,]*)\s*'` comma exclusion is needed